# Reverse linked list in java

Tags: java, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I would like to know if this is a valid recursive solution and if any improvements can be made. I've tested this solution with a few inputs and it seems to work.

```
public Node reverse(Node head) {

if(head == null) {
    return null;
}

if (head.next == null) {
    this.head = head;
    return head;
}

Node n = head.next;
head.next = null;   

reverse(n).next = head; 

return head;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: do you want to reverse based on the head node? Or do you want to reverse a full node list?

Comment: I want to reverse the whole list and then return the new head node.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of algorithm, I think this method does what you want, I believe  you wanted a linked list

A->B->C

to be converted to

C->B->A, and return A.

I am just a little confused with the scope of this method, is it a instance method of Node? what "this" is at line 8.

One thing I am not sure is, if you do not keep other pointers to C and B, after the reverse is done, then you are left with the list C->B->A, with a returned pointer to A. It looks like C and B are not pointed by any variables, won't it be garbage collected? and removed? Maybe this problem is solved by the "this" thing.

A good practice of constructing a list should be a method that return the head of a list. But your method returns the tail.
I suggest make this an instance method of Node, then you make the reverse() method to be called with head, and return the new head

```
public Node reverse() {

    if (this.next == null) {    
        return this;
    }

    Node n = this.next;
    Node newhead=n.reverse()  // After reverse, n should be at the tail 
    n.next = this; 

    return newhead;
}
```

something like this, but I have not tested the code

Comment: Thank you. I actually wanted to return the head, but forgot to add the implementation. Should the reverse() not be an instance of the linked list class? Are we not reversing the list here?

Comment: I see what you mean now, sorry I did not realize this method is in linkedlist. In your case you code works. It is just different coding style really, I always make recursive on Node objects, expecially for list, trees and stuff. If you are extending the original java.util.LinkedList, then I suggest look into the sourcecode, I think there is more  variables than just the header.  According to http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/LinkedList-source.html  there is also "first" "last" etc.

Comment: Thank you, no I'm just practising writing recursive code and also list related code. How do I make my code return the new head instead of the tail? And also, I don't quite understand how my "head.next = null;" line of code works. I wrote it to set the original head to null, but will it not set the head everytime to null?

Comment: @Prasanna in your method, the "head" that you eventually return is actually the new tail, so setting the next to be null is the right move. The place where you set the head of the entire linked list is actually the line this.head = head; which make sense, when you reach the end of your current list, you set that to your new head. So if you have original  LinkedList l1, after you do reverse, you get a newlist. Node n=l1.reverse(l1.head) n would be the original head, which is the new list tail. l1 itself is changed, when you call l1.head again, you would get the original tail

Comment: Thank you again for helping me out. Sorry, I don't quite understand returning the head part. In my program, if the input list is 1->2>3>4, the list gets changed to 4->3->2->1, but I return 1, which is the old head intead of 4, which is what I intend to return. How should I do that? I thought setting this.head = head would do that because I do that when the code gets to the tail of my original list, but why does it not work as intended?

Comment: usually a recursive method does not just work exactly the way you want, for your convenience, the reverse() returns the tail of your list, which is 1. In your code, the parameter (head) is passed in and eventually returned, means when you call reverse(1), it should return 1. Notice your method does not return the instance variable (this.head), it returned (head). they are different. So if you do x=l.reverse(1), then system.out.print(l.head), you should get 4, but System.out.print(x), you should get 1.